# Does use of 'virtualenv' leave my "real" Python installation alone?

Tags: virtualenv

I've had many questions about Python for which a suggested answer is often "use [`virtualenv`](http://www.virtualenv.org)", but I have a (lovingly maintained and perfectly functioning) Python installation that I'm loath to disturb.

I want to be absolutely sure, so I'll ask twice: Does use of `virtualenv` in any way disturb my "real" Python installation? Using `virtualenv` does not in any way modify the files or paths in my "real" installation, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtualenv creates separated Python environment. Python interpreter is linked from one of system-installed that you choose creating virtualenv( --python commandline switch) and, optionally, wheater use or not system site-packages (--system-site-packages).
All packages that you install using virtualenv remains only on virtualenv directory site-packages folder and do not mess system packages.

Comment: And *nothing* that happens while setting up or running within a virtualenv will create or modify *anything* in my file structure outside or settings outside of the sandbox of the virtualenv, correct? (For example, even if I run pip from within a virtualenv, the packages it affects will not go near my "real" installation, correct?)